# Is it possible to infer this relation without calculation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $A\sim \mathscr{E}(\alpha)$ and $B\sim\mathscr{E}(\beta)$. Is it possible to argue that:

$$\beta\,\mathbb{P}(A>B)=\alpha\,\mathbb{P}(B>A)$$

*without* calculating $\mathbb{P}(A>B)$ or $\mathbb{P}(B>A)?$

Comment: What does $A\sim \mathscr{E}(\alpha)$ mean? $A$ is an exponential random variable with $f(a) = \alpha \exp(-a\alpha)$?

Comment: @LordSoth Yes!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f_A(a) = \alpha e^{-a\alpha}$ and $f_B(b) = \beta e^{-b\beta}$, then
\begin{align}
\alpha P(A>B) & = \alpha \int_{0}^{\infty} P(A>b)f_B(b)\mathrm{d}b \\
& = \alpha \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha b}\beta e^{-\beta b} \mathrm{d}b \\
& = \beta \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\beta b}\alpha e^{-\alpha b}  \mathrm{d}b \\
& = \beta \int_{0}^{\infty} P(B>b)f_A(b)  \mathrm{d}b \\
& = \beta P(B>A).
\end{align}
Also, as Did notes below, one can stop once observing that the second line is symmetric in $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: +1. One could even argue that the second line is symmetric in (alpha,beta) and stop there.

Comment: @Did True. BTW, a proof without writing down the integral would also be nice, but I cannot see it right now.

Comment: Yes, but what you proposed is already quite nice, imho.